# CTC classification for License Plate with two lines

Tags: tensorflow

I have gone through this tutorial and have understanding how CTC works for end to end text recognition.

But for recognition of images with texts in two lines

[image]

Would it be able to use CTC for recognition? Sometimes, the plate may be rotated.